# caching a subsonicproject activerecord caches entire object graph

Tags: asp.net, caching, subsonic3, subsonic-active-record

I am caching a collection of activerecord rows (subsonic). When I look at the cache with ANTS Memory Profiler, I can see that some related tables to the activerecord I would like to cache are cached as well. This makes the cached items very large, because of the additionally (not needed) cached tables.

Any ideas on how to prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you will have to modify or remove the lazy-loading of relationships in the Active Record classes.

The lazy-loading behavior is generated by the ActiveRecord.tt template, starting at line 300 in [the most current version](https://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0-Templates/blob/master/ActiveRecord/ActiveRecord.tt):

```
        #region ' Foreign Keys '
<#
            List<string> fkCreated = new List<string>();
            foreach(FKTable fk in tbl.FKTables)
            {

                if(!ExcludeTables.Contains(fk.OtherTable)){
                    string propName=fk.OtherQueryable;
                    if(fkCreated.Contains(propName))
                    {
                        propName=fk.OtherQueryable+fkCreated.Count.ToString();
                    }

                    fkCreated.Add(fk.OtherQueryable);


#>
        public IQueryable<<#=fk.OtherClass #>> <#=propName #>
        {
            get
            {

                  var repo=<#=Namespace #>.<#=fk.OtherClass#>.GetRepo();
                  return from items in repo.GetAll()
                       where items.<#=CleanUp(fk.OtherColumn)#> == _<#=CleanUp(fk.ThisColumn)#>
                       select items;
            }
        }

<#
                }
            }

#>
        #endregion
```

I would try removing this entire region and seeing if the excessive caching is resolved.  Of course, if you rely on the lazy-loading behavior you will have to address that now.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't want to change the activerecord-template, so I created a wrapper instead with a reference by id to the row in the db so I can fetch if it needed.